# Laravel getting error on trying to save into database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sort of new to laravel i started about 3 months ago and at minute.
I'm trying to save the data you get back from twitteroath + the followers into my database but when i try to save it gets a error. Atm i'm working with laravel 5.6 and php 7.6

---

This is my code in the store fuction in my controller. everything in my controller up to the save works getting every date even the $twitter = new twitter works. if i dump()/dd() the $twitter at the end it will have to correct info. but once i add the $twitter->save(); its give back a error

```
    define('CONSUMER_KEY', getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'));
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'));
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', getenv('TWITTER_OAUTH_CALLBACK'));

    $request_token = [];
    $request_token['oauth_token'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
    $request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
        return redirect::to('dashboard.settings.index')->with('message', 'Login Failed!');
    }

    //This is for getting the twitteroath access_tokens, id and screenname.
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", ["oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']]);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

    //This is used to get the the follower count
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials', ['tweet_mode' => 'extended', 'include_entities' => 'true']);

    $twitter = new twitter;
    $twitter->twitter_id = $access_token['user_id'];
    $twitter->auth_token = $access_token['oauth_token'];
    $twitter->auth_token_secret = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    $twitter->username = $access_token['screen_name'];
    $twitter->followers = $user->followers_count;
    $twitter->save();  //<--- this is where is gets the error
    return redirect('/dashboard/settings');
```

---

And this is my model to connect to my database

```
<?php 
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class twitter extends Model
{
   public function twitter_post()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\twitter_post');
   }

   public function ContactInformation()
   {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ContactInformation');
   }
}
```

---

In case sombody wants it here is also my table in my database.

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR8Wo.png)

I wonder what i am doing wrong is a very tiny mistake what i am looking right over.

---

EDIT

I forgot to post the error in here my bad.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `twitters` (`twitter_id`, `auth_token`,
>   `auth_token_secret`, `username`, `followers`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (123, test, test, test, 123, 2018-11-01 10:50:18,
>   2018-11-01 10:50:18))

This is the error i get back.

Comment: Error which we should guess? `php 7.6` - questions from future!

Comment: can you show what error you are getting?

Comment: Welp first i got back that i couldent find the database table now i see that i have fixed that error i am just a blind person who dident look at the error correctly my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following code in your model

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

and try again

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. now i know that for in the future.

Comment: you can upvote the answers, so that it can be a reference in the future for others having the same problem.